I cannot find the way to return page and source using the LCEL
I need assistance with organizing and returning metadata in my Python script. Specifically, I have data sourced from multiple pages and want to output both the page numbers and the source names associated with each data point. For instance, if 'xx' comes from page 1 and 'yy' from page 4 of document 'a.pdf', I aim to generate outputs like: page: [1, 4] and source: ['a.pdf', 'a.pdf'].
I'm working with a small document, 'a.pdf', which comprises only 8 pages. I'm seeking a solution that avoids embedding the entire document .
loader = PyPDFLoader('xxx.csv')
data = loader.load()

model = VertexAI(
    model_name="text-bison@001",
    max_output_tokens=512,
    temperature=0.0,
    top_p=0.8,
    top_k=40,
    verbose=True,
)

class Document(BaseModel):
    xx: List[str] = Field(description="..")
    yy: List[str] = Field(description="..")
    source: List[str] = Field(description="Metadata containing source")
    page: List[str] = Field(description="Metadata containing page")

parser = JsonOutputParser(pydantic_object = Document)

prompt = PromptTemplate(

    template="""
        {context}
        ....
        {format_instructions}
        Question:{question}
        """,

    input_variables=["question", "context"],
    partial_variables={"format_instructions": parser.get_format_instructions()},
)

chain = prompt | model | parser

chain.invoke{("question": "...", "context": data")}

I attempted to incorporate specific instructions within the template to help the language model generate the source and page information. While this approach proved effective for certain documents, it wasn't universally successful and yielded varied results across different texts.
